# Reactstrap Modal не работает

Tags: reactjs

У меня такая проблема. Я делал запрос на API, получил данный и отображал на странице. Теперь хочу сделать так чтобы рядом с каждой категории был кнопка **Показать** и при нажатии открывалось модальный окно. Но когда я хочу создать эту кнопку вылетает ошибка.

**Вот код**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Table, Button, Modal, ModalHeader, ModalBody, ModalFooter} from 'reactstrap';
import './Category.css';


function CategoryData(props) {
    const category = props.category;
    return (
        <div>
            <Table>
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {category.map(item =>
                    // Атрибут key используется react для обеспечения соответствия элементов dom объектам данных.
                    <tr key={item.id}>
                        <th>{item.id}</th>
                        <th>{item.name}</th>
                        {(item.status === '1')
                            ? <th> Active </th>
                            : <th> Is active </th>
                        }
                        <div>
                            <Button color="danger" onClick={this.toggle}>Показать</Button>
                            <Modal isOpen={this.state.modal} toggle={this.toggle} className={this.props.className}>
                                <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggle}>Modal title</ModalHeader>
                                <ModalBody>
                                    Lorem ipsum
                                </ModalBody>
                                <ModalFooter>
                                    <Button color="primary" onClick={this.toggle}>Do Something</Button>{' '}
                                    <Button color="secondary" onClick={this.toggle}>Cancel</Button>
                                </ModalFooter>
                            </Modal>
                        </div>
                    </tr>
                )}
                </tbody>
            </Table>
        </div>
    );
}

class Category extends Component {

    constructor(prop) {
        super(prop);
        // установить начальное состояние
        this.state = {category: [],   modal: false};

        this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
    }

    toggle() {
        this.setState({
            modal: !this.state.modal
        });
    }

    // метод жизненного цикла
    componentDidMount() {
        // fetch + api
        fetch('http://localhost:3004/category')
            .then(data => data.json())
            .then((data) => {
                // установить состояние с помощью this.setState
                this.setState({category: data});
            });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <CategoryData category={this.state.category}/>
        );
    }
}

export default Category;
```

**И ошибка**

TypeError: Cannot read property 'toggle' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ваша CategoryData не знает контекста this из вашего класса.

Просто сделайте еще 1 props:

```
<CategoryData category={this.state.category} toggle={this.toggle} />
```

Тогда внутри CategoryData вы будете использовать props.toggle вместо this.toggle

**UPD:** сделайте еще 1 props:

```
<CategoryData category={this.state.category} toggle={this.toggle} isOpen={this.state.modal}/>
```

Тогда ваш Modal:

```
<Modal isOpen={props.isOpen} toggle={props.toggle} />
```

---

*P.S: `className={this.props.className}` эта часть тоже не сработает*

Comment: изменил так как вы написал, 'className={this.props.className}' , убрал но сейчас такой ошибка у меня, вот скришот сделал.
https://cloud.mail.ru/public/FXpx/7VJBDdDfs

Comment: надо this.toggle заменить на props.toggle

Comment: Простите что еще раз спрашиваю, просто я новичок.  this.toggle заменил на props.toggle в модальный окне, а теперь 'state' of undefined. Скрин https://cloud.mail.ru/public/NEhe/5D9uCgMiM  если вам не трудно, помогите...

Comment: отписался в ответе

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо!